# Save to Oracle joined table using ID

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datagridview

I save data from my form to Oracle DB table. Now I need to store data in joined table If my datagridview rows are not empty too, but this is where I got stucked. Joined table has ID_Table1_FK.  Here is what I tried:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Using con As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=MyDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table1(ID_Table1_PK, E_NAME, E_SURNAME, DESCRIPTION, ENTRY_DATE)
                               VALUES(MyTable_seq.nextval,: ID,: Name,: Surname,: Desc,: Entry)"

            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("ID", TxtName.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Surname", TxtSurname.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Desc", TxtDesc.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Entry", DtpEntry.Value.ToShortTimeString))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End Using

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                If row.Cells(0).Value = Nothing Then

                Else
                    Using cmd1 As New OracleCommand()

                    cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table_Join (ID_Table1, ID_Table_Join, ADDRESS, STATE)
                                         VALUES(ID_Table1,: MyTable_seq.nextval,: address,: state)"

                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("ID_Table1", "WHAT SHOULD GO HERE??"))
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("address", row.Cells(0).Value))
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("state", row.Cells(1).Value))
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    End Using

                End If

         End Using

     End Sub
```

So basically I need any advice on how to pass same ID value to another (joined) table ?

P.S.: "MyTable_seq.nextval" is triggering automatic sequence number of records in DB.

Comment: I guess you are looking for the [Returning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) keyword. [Here](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server-cs-conversion/insert-returning-clause) you can find an example how to use it with .NET

Comment: You can add additional query in your program and get new ID value for further using.
For exmple, you can use query like this `select MyTable_seq.nextval from dual`. Execute it first,  save result into variable and then use value from variable as parmeter in your others queries.

Comment: @AlexB., thanks, will try this on Monday and let you know about It.

Comment: @Surename, I don't quite follow you on this one. I need to specify which "MyTable_seg.nextval" to obtain, I can't just select It, many records under same table. Also I have one specific problem: I'm using same OracleCommand in code with If statements, and in one of the "If's" I need to use this join query - Is this ok or should I first end using  OracleCommand and then start another ?

Comment: @AlexB., unfortunally RETURNING doesn't work for me. I allways get error in line for adding parameter.

Comment: @Surename, It doesn't work properly. I get ID value, but then It somehow generates new autonumbers, don't know why. Example: record ID is 200 & I get 200 returned ("cmd.ExecuteScalar - 1" - otherwise I get next Autonumber), and when saving next record in DB, my autonmuber jumps to 220 (20 records skipped??). I mentioned, "MyTable_seq.nextval" is a sequence created in OracleDB.